# pagination in ASP.NET MVC without using any external nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

Could you please let me know is there any way to do the pagination in ASP.NET MVC without using any external nuget package(Eg : PageList.mvc). Actually I'm looking for a server side solution to do the pagination in MVC itself.

Please help me if some one know the answer.

Thanks
Nishad

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx). It's not a NuGet package, it's part of the `System.Web.Helpers` namespace and provides pagination functionality out of the box.

**1.Model:**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**2.View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCTutorial.Models.Product>

@{
    Layout = null;
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 2);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "table",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("ID", "ID", format: @<text> @item.ID
    </text>, style: "p13"),
    grid.Column("Description","Description", format: @<text> @item.Description</text>)))
```

**3.Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        var p1 = new Product { ID = 1, Description = "Product 1" };
        var p2 = new Product { ID = 2, Description = "Product 2" };
        var p3 = new Product { ID = 3, Description = "Product 3" };
        var p4 = new Product { ID = 4, Description = "Product 4" };

        var products = new List<Product> { p1, p2, p3, p4 };

        return View(products);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denis. This will be very helpful to me. This is the thing actually I was finding. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Denis, Could you place let me know how to pass parameter as ActionResult GetProducts(bool value) to the action action method when  I click on each paging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and pass the pageNumber and resultsPerPage to a controller.

```
var entries = _dbContext.YourTable.OrderBy(e => e.Date).Skip(pageNumber - 1).Take(resultsPerPage);
```

Your logic should also calculate how many pages there will be by getting the count of records for your particular query and doing some basic math.

Here's a good example: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/10/30/ASPNET-MVC-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx